# Update sql table by dropdownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I have dropdownlist (`id="myDDL"`).

I have the method (`updateTable_byDDL`) for update my sql table, the method work great when I put manual value in the `SET="bla"` ..

But when I write in the `SET= '"+ myDDL.Text.ToString() + "'`, the column on the SQL update to empty.

The dropdownlist is binding from array that I put outside the `page_load` (in the class), and I am binding it on the page load:

```
    myDDL.DataSource = array;
    myDDL.DataBind();
```

In the aspx page I can see well the array values in the dropdownlist, but after I chose the item I want - and click on the button, the column turn to empty.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: That's textbook injection attack material.

Comment: Can you explain, @P.Brian.Mackey ?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648339.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the info, i will use that in the future. but for now - that site is only for my use only in my computer...

Comment: Oh, if only I got $1 for every time a "this-is-for-local-test-only" feature got to production...

Comment: No, really, that for my use only. in my sites i already used parameters without know the injection part. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You should take `myDDL.SelectedItem.Text`
2. You should use parameters to avoid SQL injection

Check it out:

```
   YourUpdateCommand.CommandText = "UPDATE table SET column = @NewValue WHERE conditions";

   YourUpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@NewValue", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, 100); //or whatever

   YourUpdateCommand.Parameters["@NewValue"].Value = myDDL.SelectedItem.Text;

   YourUpdateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: Your suggestion is a good one regarding SQL Injection attacks; however, the issue is not that he isn't doing `myDDL.SelectedItem` since `myDDL.Text` is the same as doing `myDDL.SelectedItem.Value` or `myDDL.SelectedValue`. Here's the MSDN reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.dropdownlist.aspx

Comment: Work like a charm. i'll take also everybody suggestion for the injection attacks. Thanks !

Comment: @Icarus They're not the same thing. I'm suggesting the `SelectedItem.Text`, not the `SelectedValue`.

Comment: @Bside Please, don't forget to mark the answer as correct if it's what you were looking for.

Comment: @AndreCalil If you bind to an `Array` of primitive types, `Text` and `Value` properties in the `DropDown` become the same thing. The only time it makes a difference is when you explicitly set the `DataTextField` and `DataValueField` properties in the `DropDownList`, which doesn't seem to be the case here. Regardless, your answer somehow helped him solve the issue.

Answer (score 2):

In case you bind your DDL in page_load it will get bound EVERY time your page loads. So in a quick guess of your code, all you have to do is add an if statement to check if page.isPostback

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        ddlDemo.DataSource = new string[] { "asdf", "jklö" };
        ddlDemo.DataBind();
    }
}

protected void btnDemo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(ddlDemo.Text);
    SqlConnection con = null;
    using (con = new SqlConnection("YOUR CON STRING"))
    {
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand( "update tblXYZ set ABC = @A", con);
        SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter("A", System.Data.SqlDbType.YOURTYPE);
        param.Value = ddlDemo.Text;
        com.Parameters.Add(param);
        con.Open();
        int affectedRows = com.ExecuteNonQuery();
        Debug.WriteLine(affectedRows + " affected!");
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

within this aspx page

```
<body>
  <form id="form1" runat="server">

    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlDemo" runat="server">
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:Button ID="btnDemo" runat="server" Text="Button" onclick="btnDemo_Click" />
  </form>
</body>
```

Anyway you should always check user input before using it to update/insert/delete any database records!